# I'm not getting something about this differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I think I am missing something basic in my understanding of this differential equation...

Im on the book "Linear Algebra and Its Applications" by Gilbert Strang Section 5.3 about differential equations. I never had to take these in school so I feel a bit lost although I did take calculus.

On page 254 it goes through an interest example at a bank and then comes to the conclusion that the differential equation...

$$
\frac{dp}{dt} = .06p
$$

has the solution

$$
p(t) = e^{.06t}p_0
$$

By my understanding of differential equations, I should be looking for the equation which has a derivative of $.06p$, but the calculus I know would put the derivative of the given solution at

$$
\frac{dp}{dt} = .06p_0e^{.06t}
$$

I must be missing something. Can you see what it is?

Comment: You have $p = p(t) = 0.06p_0 e^{0.06t}$ use that in the last line

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean, could you elaborate more?

Comment: You have got $0.06\color{red}{p_0e^{0.06t}} = 0.06\color{red}{p(t)} \equiv 0.06\color{red} p$

Answer (score 2):

You have done it correct, note that

$$\frac{\mathrm {d}p}{\mathrm dt} = .06\underbrace{p_0\mathrm e^{.06t}}_{= p} = .06p,$$

as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Your $p$ is a function of $t$, while the $p_0$ in the solution is a constant (like 2,$\pi$ etc.) Basically the $p_0$ is found when you're given initial conditions i.e. $p(0)=p_0$.

Your own calculation is correct, indeed: $p(t)=p_0e^{0.06 t}$

Comment: that is not my own calculation though, that is what the book said. My own calculation is on the last line

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an initial value problem of the type:

$$ \frac{dp}{dt} = kp, \hskip 5pt p(0) = p_{0}.$$

This can be solved using separation of variables, upon which

$$ p(t) = p_{0}e^{kt}.$$

Hence, given the specific problem:

$$\frac{dp}{dt} = .06p, \hskip 5pt p(0) = p_{0}$$

The solution is

$$ p(t) = p_{0}e^{.06t}.$$